Legend not showing up using Matplotlib
I have been trying to add a legend to my graph, but it keeps showing up as just a small empty box, and I don't know how to fix this.

Here is my code:
    plot.figure(figureLabel)
    plot.title(plotTitle)
    plot.xlabel(xLabel)
    plot.ylabel(yLabel)
    plot.scatter(xAxis, yAxis,color=color)
    plot.errorbar(xAxis, yAxis, xerr=xError, yerr =yError,ls='none')
    
    curvefit = CurveFit(xAxis,yAxis,yError)
    slope = curvefit[0][0]
    yIntercept = curvefit[0][1]
    plot.plot(xAxis, (xAxis*slope + yIntercept),color = 'black')
    plot.legend()


You should label your plotted data to get something as a legend. For example, instead of plot.scatter(xAxis, yAxis,color=color) try plot.scatter(xAxis, yAxis,color=color, label="Data") or instead of plot.errorbar(xAxis, yAxis, xerr=xError, yerr =yError,ls='none') try plot.errorbar(xAxis, yAxis, xerr=xError, yerr =yError,ls='none', label="Error bars") and so on

Note that using matplotlib's pyplot as plot instead of the standard plt makes your code much harder to compare to examples in the tutorials and elsewhere. It also makes it harder for others to quickly understand the code.
